# Generic paramater that itself is generic

Tags: dart

I have a factory class that is generic over `T extends SomeClass<A>`. But the thing is that `A` isn't known at the class level but only at the method level. To make myself a bit clearer with some code:

```
class Factory<T extends SomeClass<A>> { // Don't know A here
  T<A> Function<A>(A arg) _constructor; // Function that produces my T's and is generic over A
  Factory(this._constructor);
  
  T<String> newString(String arg){      // A is only known here
    return _constructor(arg);
  }
  T<int> newInt(int arg){
    return _constructor(arg);
  }
}
```

This obviously isn't legal Dart code, but is something to that effect even possible with Dart's generics, or does it require code generation? I tried to use extension methods, but they don't solve the problem that `_constructor` has the return type `T<A>`. And I explicitly don't want to / can't use `T constructor<A, T extends SomeClass<A>>(A args)`.

**Edit:** I think what I was actually asking for is higher kinded types, which categorically aren't possible in Dart, and there is ongoing discussion on this matter (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1655). Excuse me if my understanding of the matter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not *directly* possible the way Dart currently works.
Dart's generics are only *first order*, so you cannot pass what is essentially a function from type to type as a type argument. Only plain types can be type arguments.

What you have here is a generic factory class. The kind of object it creates is defined at the class level (for ease, let's just assume that `SomeClass` here is `Iterable`, so it's a collection factory class, and you can choose, e.g., `List` or `Set` or `Queue` as the kind of collection to create), and then the *element type* of those collections are chosen when you call the factory methods.
That cannot work, because there is no *type* that the class can store in the class type argument which can allow that usage later.

I'd probably use separate classes and normal inheritance for this:

```dart
abstract class Factory {
  Iterable<T> Function<T>(T) _constructor;
  Factory(Iterable<T> Function<T>(T) constructor) 
      : _constructor = constructor;
  Iterable<String> newString(String arg) => _constructor<String>(arg);
  Iterable<int> newINt(int arg) => _constructor<int>(arg);
}
class ListFactory extends Factory {
  ListFactory(List<T> Function<T>(T) constructor) : super(constructor);
  List<String> newString(String arg) => 
      super.newString(arg) as List<String>;
  List<int> newInt(int arg) => 
      super.newInt(arg) as List<int>;
}
```

Comment: If I have to override each and every method anyway to do type assertion, then there isn't much point to what I had in mind, and I would be better off using code generation, both for productivity and performance.